# Direct3D 11 or DXUT11 needs some additional libs i guess.

Tags: direct3d11, dxut

When i am building  my solution  i  am getting  these  build time  errors.

1>DDSTextureLoader.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "enum DXGI_FORMAT **cdecl MAKE_SRGB(enum DXGI_FORMAT)" (?MAKE_SRGB@@YA?AW4DXGI_FORMAT@@W41@@Z) referenced in function "long __cdecl CreateTextureFromDDS(struct ID3D11Device *,struct DDS_HEADER *,unsigned char *,unsigned int,struct ID3D11ShaderResourceView * *,bool)" (?CreateTextureFromDDS@@YAJPAUID3D11Device@@PAUDDS_HEADER@@PAEIPAPAUID3D11ShaderResourceView@@_N@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackFrameMove(void (__stdcall*)(double,float,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackFrameMove@@YGXP6GXNMPAX@Z0@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackMsgProc(long (__stdcall*)(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long,bool *,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackMsgProc@@YGXP6GJPAUHWND__@@IIJPA_NPAX@Z2@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void **stdcall DXUTSetCallbackDeviceChanging(bool (__stdcall***)(struct DXUTDeviceSettings *,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackDeviceChanging@@YGXP6G_NPAUDXUTDeviceSettings@@PAX@Z1@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceAcceptable(bool (__stdcall*)(class CD3D11EnumAdapterInfo const *,unsigned int,class CD3D11EnumDeviceInfo const *,enum DXGI_FORMAT,bool,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceAcceptable@@YGXP6G_NPBVCD3D11EnumAdapterInfo@@IPBVCD3D11EnumDeviceInfo@@W4DXGI_FORMAT@@_NPAX@Z4@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceCreated(long (__stdcall*)(struct ID3D11Device *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceCreated@@YGXP6GJPAUID3D11Device@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@PAX@Z2@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D11SwapChainResized(long (__stdcall*)(struct ID3D11Device *,struct IDXGISwapChain *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D11SwapChainResized@@YGXP6GJPAUID3D11Device@@PAUIDXGISwapChain@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@PAX@Z3@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D11FrameRender(void (__stdcall*)(struct ID3D11Device *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext *,double,float,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D11FrameRender@@YGXP6GXPAUID3D11Device@@PAUID3D11DeviceContext@@NMPAX@Z2@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D11SwapChainReleasing(void (__stdcall*)(void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D11SwapChainReleasing@@YGXP6GXPAX@Z0@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceDestroyed(void (__stdcall*)(void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceDestroyed@@YGXP6GXPAX@Z0@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall DXUTInit(bool,bool,wchar_t *,bool)" (?DXUTInit@@YGJ_N0PA_W0@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall DXUTCreateWindow(wchar_t const *,struct HINSTANCE *,struct HICON__ *,struct HMENU__ *,int,int)" (?DXUTCreateWindow@@YGJPB_WPAUHINSTANCE__@@PAUHICON__@@PAUHMENU__@@HH@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long **stdcall DXUTCreateDevice(enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL,bool,int,int)" (?DXUTCreateDevice@@YGJW4D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL@@_NHH@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall DXUTMainLoop(struct HACCEL** *)" (?DXUTMainLoop@@YGJPAUHACCEL__@@@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long **stdcall DXUTToggleFullScreen(void)" (?DXUTToggleFullScreen@@YGJXZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnGUIEvent(unsigned int,int,class CDXUTControl *,void *)" (?OnGUIEvent@@YGXIHPAVCDXUTControl@@PAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCursorSettings(bool,bool)" (?DXUTSetCursorSettings@@YGX_N0@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetIsInGammaCorrectMode(bool)" (?DXUTSetIsInGammaCorrectMode@@YGX_N@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const * __stdcall DXUTGetDXGIBackBufferSurfaceDesc(void)" (?DXUTGetDXGIBackBufferSurfaceDesc@@YGPBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@XZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnFrameMove(double,float,void *)" (?OnFrameMove@@YGXNMPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct ID3D11Device * __stdcall DXUTGetD3D11Device(void)" (?DXUTGetD3D11Device@@YGPAUID3D11Device@@XZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnFrameMove(double,float,void *)" (?OnFrameMove@@YGXNMPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "wchar_t const * __stdcall DXUTGetFrameStats(bool)" (?DXUTGetFrameStats@@YGPB_W_N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl RenderText(void)" (?RenderText@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "wchar_t const * __stdcall DXUTGetDeviceStats(void)" (?DXUTGetDeviceStats@@YGPB_WXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl RenderText(void)" (?RenderText@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __stdcall DXUTIsVsyncEnabled(void)" (?DXUTIsVsyncEnabled@@YG_NXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl RenderText(void)" (?RenderText@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall DXUTGetExitCode(void)" (?DXUTGetExitCode@@YGHXZ) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall DXUTTrace(char const *,unsigned long,long,wchar_t const *,bool)" (?DXUTTrace@@YGJPBDKJPB_W_N@Z) referenced in function "long __cdecl CompileGaussianFilterEffects(struct ID3D11Device *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *)" (?CompileGaussianFilterEffects@@YAJPAUID3D11Device@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@@Z)
    1>SkyBox11.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall DXUTTrace(char const *,unsigned long,long,wchar_t const *,bool)" (?DXUTTrace@@YGJPBDKJPB_W_N@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CBaseCamera::SetProjParams(float,float,float,float)" (?SetProjParams@CBaseCamera@@UAEXMMMM@Z) referenced in function "long __stdcall OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain(struct ID3D11Device *,struct IDXGISwapChain *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *,void *)" (?OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain@@YGJPAUID3D11Device@@PAUIDXGISwapChain@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@PAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CModelViewerCamera::CModelViewerCamera(void)" (??0CModelViewerCamera@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'g_Camera''(void)" (??__Eg_Camera@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __thiscall CModelViewerCamera::HandleMessages(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?HandleMessages@CModelViewerCamera@@UAEJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) referenced in function "long __stdcall MsgProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long,bool *,void *)" (?MsgProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJPA_NPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CModelViewerCamera::FrameMove(float)" (?FrameMove@CModelViewerCamera@@UAEXM@Z) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnFrameMove(double,float,void *)" (?OnFrameMove@@YGXNMPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CDXUTDialog::CDXUTDialog(void)" (??0CDXUTDialog@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl`dynamic initializer for 'g_HUD''(void)" (??__Eg_HUD@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CDXUTDialog::~CDXUTDialog(void)" (??1CDXUTDialog@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'g_HUD''(void)" (??__Fg_HUD@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CDXUTDialog::Init(class CDXUTDialogResourceManager *,bool)" (?Init@CDXUTDialog@@QAEXPAVCDXUTDialogResourceManager@@_N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitApp(void)" (?InitApp@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall CDXUTDialog::MsgProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?MsgProc@CDXUTDialog@@QAE_NPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) referenced in function "long __stdcall MsgProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long,bool *,void *)" (?MsgProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJPA_NPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTDialog::AddStatic(int,wchar_t const *,int,int,int,int,bool,class CDXUTStatic * *)" (?AddStatic@CDXUTDialog@@QAEJHPB_WHHHH_NPAPAVCDXUTStatic@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitApp(void)" (?InitApp@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTDialog::AddButton(int,wchar_t const *,int,int,int,int,unsigned int,bool,class CDXUTButton * *)" (?AddButton@CDXUTDialog@@QAEJHPB_WHHHHI_NPAPAVCDXUTButton@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitApp(void)" (?InitApp@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTDialog::AddComboBox(int,int,int,int,int,unsigned int,bool,class CDXUTComboBox * *)" (?AddComboBox@CDXUTDialog@@QAEJHHHHHI_NPAPAVCDXUTComboBox@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitApp(void)" (?InitApp@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTDialog::AddSlider(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,bool,class CDXUTSlider * *)" (?AddSlider@CDXUTDialog@@QAEJHHHHHHHH_NPAPAVCDXUTSlider@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitApp(void)" (?InitApp@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class CDXUTControl * __thiscall CDXUTDialog::GetControl(int,unsigned int)const " (?GetControl@CDXUTDialog@@QBEPAVCDXUTControl@@HI@Z) referenced in function "public: class CDXUTComboBox * __thiscall CDXUTDialog::GetComboBox(int)const " (?GetComboBox@CDXUTDialog@@QBEPAVCDXUTComboBox@@H@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CDXUTDialog::SetCallback(void (__stdcall*)(unsigned int,int,class CDXUTControl *,void *),void *)" (?SetCallback@CDXUTDialog@@QAEXP6GXIHPAVCDXUTControl@@PAX@Z1@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitApp(void)" (?InitApp@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTDialog::OnRender(float)" (?OnRender@CDXUTDialog@@QAEJM@Z) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnD3D11FrameRender(struct ID3D11Device *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext *,double,float,void *)" (?OnD3D11FrameRender@@YGXPAUID3D11Device@@PAUID3D11DeviceContext@@NMPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CDXUTDialogResourceManager::CDXUTDialogResourceManager(void)" (??0CDXUTDialogResourceManager@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl`dynamic initializer for 'g_DialogResourceManager''(void)" (??__Eg_DialogResourceManager@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CDXUTDialogResourceManager::~CDXUTDialogResourceManager(void)" (??1CDXUTDialogResourceManager@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'g_DialogResourceManager''(void)" (??__Fg_DialogResourceManager@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall CDXUTDialogResourceManager::MsgProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?MsgProc@CDXUTDialogResourceManager@@QAE_NPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) referenced in function "long __stdcall MsgProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long,bool *,void *)" (?MsgProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJPA_NPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTDialogResourceManager::OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain(struct ID3D11Device *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *)" (?OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain@CDXUTDialogResourceManager@@QAEJPAUID3D11Device@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@@Z) referenced in function "long __stdcall OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain(struct ID3D11Device *,struct IDXGISwapChain *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *,void *)" (?OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain@@YGJPAUID3D11Device@@PAUIDXGISwapChain@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@PAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CDXUTDialogResourceManager::OnD3D11ReleasingSwapChain(void)" (?OnD3D11ReleasingSwapChain@CDXUTDialogResourceManager@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnD3D11ReleasingSwapChain(void *)" (?OnD3D11ReleasingSwapChain@@YGXPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CDXUTDialogResourceManager::OnD3D11DestroyDevice(void)" (?OnD3D11DestroyDevice@CDXUTDialogResourceManager@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnD3D11DestroyDevice(void *)" (?OnD3D11DestroyDevice@@YGXPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTStatic::SetText(wchar_t const *)" (?SetText@CDXUTStatic@@QAEJPB_W@Z) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnGUIEvent(unsigned int,int,class CDXUTControl *,void *)" (?OnGUIEvent@@YGXIHPAVCDXUTControl@@PAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTComboBox::AddItem(wchar_t const *,void *)" (?AddItem@CDXUTComboBox@@QAEJPB_WPAX@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitApp(void)" (?InitApp@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void * __thiscall CDXUTComboBox::GetSelectedData(void)const " (?GetSelectedData@CDXUTComboBox@@QBEPAXXZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnGUIEvent(unsigned int,int,class CDXUTControl *,void *)" (?OnGUIEvent@@YGXIHPAVCDXUTControl@@PAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CD3DSettingsDlg::CD3DSettingsDlg(void)" (??0CD3DSettingsDlg@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl`dynamic initializer for 'g_D3DSettingsDlg''(void)" (??__Eg_D3DSettingsDlg@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CD3DSettingsDlg::~CD3DSettingsDlg(void)" (??1CD3DSettingsDlg@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'g_D3DSettingsDlg''(void)" (??__Fg_D3DSettingsDlg@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CD3DSettingsDlg::Init(class CDXUTDialogResourceManager *)" (?Init@CD3DSettingsDlg@@QAEXPAVCDXUTDialogResourceManager@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitApp(void)" (?InitApp@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CD3DSettingsDlg::OnRender(float)" (?OnRender@CD3DSettingsDlg@@QAEXM@Z) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnD3D11FrameRender(struct ID3D11Device *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext *,double,float,void *)" (?OnD3D11FrameRender@@YGXPAUID3D11Device@@PAUID3D11DeviceContext@@NMPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CD3DSettingsDlg::OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain(struct ID3D11Device *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *)" (?OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain@CD3DSettingsDlg@@QAEJPAUID3D11Device@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@@Z) referenced in function "long __stdcall OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain(struct ID3D11Device *,struct IDXGISwapChain *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *,void *)" (?OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain@@YGJPAUID3D11Device@@PAUIDXGISwapChain@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@PAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CD3DSettingsDlg::OnD3D11DestroyDevice(void)" (?OnD3D11DestroyDevice@CD3DSettingsDlg@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnD3D11DestroyDevice(void *)" (?OnD3D11DestroyDevice@@YGXPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CD3DSettingsDlg::MsgProc(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?MsgProc@CD3DSettingsDlg@@QAEJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) referenced in function "long **stdcall MsgProc(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long,bool *,void *)" (?MsgProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJPA_NPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTResourceCache::OnDestroyDevice(void)" (?OnDestroyDevice@CDXUTResourceCache@@QAEJXZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnD3D11DestroyDevice(void *)" (?OnD3D11DestroyDevice@@YGXPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class CDXUTResourceCache & __stdcall DXUTGetGlobalResourceCache(void)" (?DXUTGetGlobalResourceCache@@YGAAVCDXUTResourceCache@@XZ) referenced in function "void __stdcall OnD3D11DestroyDevice(void *)" (?OnD3D11DestroyDevice@@YGXPAX@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CDXUTTextHelper::Begin(void)" (?Begin@CDXUTTextHelper@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl RenderText(void)" (?RenderText@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CDXUTTextHelper::DrawTextLine(wchar_t const *)" (?DrawTextLine@CDXUTTextHelper@@QAEJPB_W@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl RenderText(void)" (?RenderText@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CDXUTTextHelper::End(void)" (?End@CDXUTTextHelper@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl RenderText(void)" (?RenderText@@YAXXZ)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall DXUTFindDXSDKMediaFileCch(wchar_t *,int,wchar_t const *)" (?DXUTFindDXSDKMediaFileCch@@YGJPA_WHPB_W@Z) referenced in function "long __cdecl CompileGaussianFilterEffects(struct ID3D11Device *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *)" (?CompileGaussianFilterEffects@@YAJPAUID3D11Device@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall DXUTSetMediaSearchPath(wchar_t const *)" (?DXUTSetMediaSearchPath@@YGJPB_W@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory@20 referenced in function "long __cdecl CompileGaussianFilterEffects(struct ID3D11Device *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *)" (?CompileGaussianFilterEffects@@YAJPAUID3D11Device@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@@Z)
    1>mainInvoke.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall OnD3D11CreateDevice(struct ID3D11Device *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *,void *)" (?OnD3D11CreateDevice@@YGJPAUID3D11Device@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@PAX@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    1>D:\VisualStudioProjects\DX11GaussianBlur\DX11GaussianBlur\Debug\DX11GaussianBlur.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 64 unresolved externals

```
P.S.  after  building  i am  getting  that  build  time  errors , right  now i am linking these  libs: 
d3dcompiler.lib
dxguid.lib
winmm.lib
comctl32.lib
usp10.lib

Can u give me any solution  or  something else  to fix  that.
```

Comment: Which version of DXUT are you using exactly? If you are using [DXUT](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT) and [Effects 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) from GitHub, then everything should build assuming you are building them all with the same version of Visual C++.

Comment: Note that the formatting of your post makes it really hard to read, and you aren't providing much about where this solution came from or how it is set up.

Comment: Never  mind  Chuck  i have fixed  it  :).  Yeah i was linking old  libs(with previous  version  of DXUT libs).  I am using latest  version of DXUT11(I  downloaded  from  Github from  your repository) for  Windows 10 and i needed  that  output into my  solution linking(not old one). Now  project is  being  build  without  a problem.

Comment: Ok, yes that would cause problems. The legacy DirectX SDK versions of these libs only work with VS 2010.

Comment: Yeah sorry  i have copied it from  VS output :(.

Comment: If you take that output, open a new file in VS, paste it in, highlight it, and then hit TAB it will be spaced so that StackOverflow will format it consistently as code.